# Handling XML with Python

Tags: python, xml, dom

All I want to do is get the content of an XML tag in Python.  I'm maybe using the wrong import; ideally I'd love to have the way PHP deals with XML (i.e `$XML->this_tag`), like the way pyodbc does database stuff (i.e. `table.field`)

Here's my example:

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parseString
dom = parseString("<test>I want to read this</test>")
dom.getElementsByTagName("test")[0].toxml()
>>> u'<test>I want to read this</test>'
```

All I want to be able to do read the contents of the tag (like innerHTML in javascript).

Comment: maybe try `dom.getElementsByTagName("test")[0].firstChild().toxml()`

Comment: There is a useful summary of python xml support on the [python wiki](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonXml)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of `dom.getElementsByTagName("test")[0].toxml()` put `dom.getElementsByTagName("test")[0].firstChild.data` It will print the node value.

Answer (score 2):

I like BeautifulSoup :

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulStoneSoup
xml = """<test>I want to read this</test>"""
soup = BeautifulStoneSoup(xml)
soup.find('test')
```

> I want to read this

looks somewhat better.

Comment: Like it!  Will use that in a future project!

Answer (score 1):

Use `firstChild.data` instead of `toxml`:

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parseString

dom = parseString('<test>I want to read this</test>')
element = dom.getElementsByTagName('test')[0]
print element.firstChild.data
```

**Output:**

```
>>> I want to read this
```